# Converting file path to clickable hyperlink ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I am trying to print out a file path which should be displayed as a link in Intellij console output. I have tried doing the following

```
    file_path =  'C://Users'
    puts '<a href= "File:///' + file_path + '">'+ file_path + '</a>'
```

This just prints me a statement C://Users but does not change it to clickable link. Please let me know what am I missing to convert it into clickable link.

Comment: prints as <a href = "File://C://Users">C://Users</a> and not "C://Users", editor changed it somehow.

Comment: You're telling it to print `<a href="File://C://Users">C://Users</a>` and that's what it's doing so what is your expected outcome? Are you trying to make it possible to click `C://Users` in your console IRB session, and then have it open Windows Explorer? Because `<a href>` is HTML and that won't render in any console on any platform, and won't work the way you're hoping. On Linux/UNIX/macOS/etc. terminals you can generally click plaintext paths like `/Users/foo` and have it open, but that is a function of the terminal/console and has nothing to do with your code. The console must support it.

Comment: What editor? How are you running this code? Please improve your question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am running it in Intellij. I want to print the file path as a clickable link in console output

Answer (score 1):

you can use npm package for this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/terminal-link

Example:

```
            mifrill@mifrill-desktop:~$ npm install terminal-link

            npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mifrill/package.json'
            npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
            npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mifrill/package.json'
            npm WARN mifrill No description
            npm WARN mifrill No repository field.
            npm WARN mifrill No README data
            npm WARN mifrill No license field.

            + terminal-link@1.1.0
            added 6 packages from 2 contributors and audited 6 packages in 2.868s
            found 0 vulnerabilities
```

_

```
            mifrill@mifrill-desktop:~$ node

            > const terminalLink = require('terminal-link');
            undefined
```

_

```
            > console.log(terminalLink('file', 'C://Users'))

            file
```

This string (file) would be clickable

Or you can use just special characters (on ruby):

```
irb
link  = 'C://Users'
title = 'File'
puts "\u001b]8;;#{link}\u0007#{title}\u001b]8;;\u0007"
```